# How to solve 'ImageCollection (Error) Collection query aborted after accumulating over 5000 elements.'?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am having an error that:

```
ImageCollection (Error)
  Collection query aborted after accumulating over 5000 elements
```

Can anyone help me with this with a reason that I'm getting this?

```
var data = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD11A1");
           data.select('LST_Day_1km');
           data.filterDate('2020-04-01', '2020-05-01');
           data.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',50));
           data.filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-105.69039417492381, 26.415054995716197],
          [-105.69039417492381, 20.944574100188213],
          [-99.45015979992381, 20.944574100188213],
          [-99.45015979992381, 26.415054995716197]]], null, false));
print(data);
```

Link to the code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/e2d9c897f4602466c1bb14a863ec2262

Answer (score 7):

Earth Engine [documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/ic_info) says:

> ... The collection can be printed directly to the console, but the console printout is limited to 5000 elements. Collections larger than 5000 images will need to be filtered before printing. Printing a large collection will be correspondingly slower. ...

You get that error because you try to print an image collection that contains 7693 images (greater than 5000) to the console. Check `print(data.size())`.

---

Also, your script is the same as two lines of code below.

```
var data = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD11A1");        
print(data);
```

Because, you don't assign `data.select('LST_Day_1km');` (and other `data...` lines) to a variable. So, `data` stays the same.

You should use this way (remove the leading `data`s) :

```
var data = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD11A1")
  .select('LST_Day_1km')
  .filterDate('2020-04-01', '2020-05-01')
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',50))
  .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Polygon(
     [[[-105.69039417492381, 26.415054995716197],
       [-105.69039417492381, 20.944574100188213],
       [-99.45015979992381, 20.944574100188213],
       [-99.45015979992381, 26.415054995716197]]], null, false));
        
print(data);
```